# IE, jquery checkbox doesn't change

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I have this html syntax:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="openInNewWindowCheckBox" value ="some_value"  />
```

and a jquery script:

```
$("#openInNewWindowCheckBox").change(function(){

            if($(this).is(':checked'))
            { 

            }
            else
            { 

            }   

            return false; 
        });
```

and in IE i just can't change or unchange the checkbox, html for it looks like this:

```
<input id="openInNewWindowCheckBox" type="checkbox" _just_changed="true" jQuery18203967820199374023="133" value="some_value"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Returning false prevents the default action. You try returning true for that.

```
         $("#openInNewWindowCheckBox").change(function(){

        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        { 
            console.log('a');
        }
        else
        { 
            console.log('b');
        }   

        return true; 
    });
```

Comment: Or just don't return a value at all.

Comment: Basically you are binding a function to event, so it's bad idea to return true or false in cases when you does not validating some data. But there are cases where you need to prevent default functionality for exact event then you need to use .change(function(e){....}) and inside of you handler call e.preventDefault()

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, checkbox change triggers only after you blur from the checkbox in IE. Bind it to click instead.